# Implementing Image Overlays in case of Multiple Images

Tags: html, css

I tried to get an [example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidebottom) running, but in my case there are multiple images. The overlay is displayed for the entire window instead of the 1st image (I plan to do this for all images later).

Here is my code:

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
}
.col1 {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.img1-wrap {
 display: block;
}

.image {
 display: block;
 /*width: 100%;*/
 height: auto;
}

.overlay {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #008CBA;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*width: 100%;*/
 height: 20%;
 transition: .5s ease;
}

.img1-wrap:hover .overlay {
 height: 100%;
}

.text {
 white-space: nowrap; 
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="col col-1">
  <div class="img1-wrap">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
   <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image2">
 </div>
 
 <div class="col col-3">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image3">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image4">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlay several images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443002/overlay-several-images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.img1-wrap` and give a try.

> When you make a element positioned **absolute**, Make sure its parent
>   is positioned **relative**

CSS

```
  .img1-wrap {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Is this what you want to achive [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/cpnafj11/2/)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Apart from the fact that this solution is accepted one but it only shows only one image the other images are hidden. Can you kindly do it while keeping the other images intact as they were before. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are not using positioning the right way. Use `relative` for each element block with the text container.

You should restructure your HTML & CSS in such way:

```css
.flex-container {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
}

.img1-wrap {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 200px;
}

.image {
 width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #008CBA;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*width: 100%;*/
 height: 20%;
 transition: .5s ease;
}

.img1-wrap:hover .overlay {
 height: 100%;
}

.text {
 white-space: nowrap; 
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="img1-wrap">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="img1-wrap">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="img1-wrap">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="img1-wrap">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps and this is what you're trying to achieve.